# Set the language of an HTML input

Tags: html, internationalization, accessibility, markup

I am currently developing an app that handles translations. In the prototype, the app can handle translations from English to German.

Currently, I have `<textarea>` elements surrounded by `<label>` elements:

```
<label className="m-translation-card__native-field-label" 
       aria-label="Original (English)">
    English

    <textarea className="m-translation-card__native-field-input"
              placeholder="English translation"
              onChange="..." 
              value="..."
    />
</label>

<label className="m-translation-card__translated-field-label"
       aria-label="Translation (Deutsch)">
    Deutsch

    <textarea className="m-translation-card__translated-field-input"
              placeholder="German translation"
              onChange="..."
              value="..."                            
    />
</label>
```

When one navigates to the "English translation" textarea via keyboard, the screen reader will read aloud the textarea `value` attribute content in English. This makes sense - the `lang` attribute of the `<html>` tag is set to "en" - and is the intended functionality.

But, when one navigates to the "German translation" textarea, the screen reader again pronounces the textarea `value` attribute content in English - a pronunciation that is often far different to the correct German pronunciation. Ideally, the pronunciation would be in German.

I would like to add an attribute so that the screen reader is aware that the content of the second textarea is German. I have tried to use the `lang="de"` attribute, but it did not effect the pronunciation.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen readers do not guess or automatically detect the language of a string but need HTML's `lang` attribute in order to use the appropriate speech synthesis engine or Braille table (or both). (I have never seen screen reader support for XHTML's `xml:lang` attribute that is mentioned in one of the other answers.) The [`lang` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xmllang-attributes) can be used on any element, including form elements and their labels.

For example, you can use the following code in a document where `lang="en"` is already set on an ancestor element such as `html`:

```
 <label className="m-translation-card__native-field-label" for="english-translation">English </label>
 <textarea id="english-translation" className="m-translation-card__native-field-input"></textarea>

 <label className="m-translation-card__native-field-label" for="german-translation">German </label>
 <textarea id="german-translation" className="m-translation-card__native-field-input" lang="de"></textarea>
```

A few other comments:

- You don't need `aria-label` on `label` elements; a `label` element labels a form element and does not need a label for itself.
- You can wrap the label around a form element, but using it as a sibling element should give you more control about placement (e.g. next or above the textarea) by means of CSS.
- JAWS appears to "provide language switching with any supported speech synthesizer" (see [Languages with JAWS and MAGic on the Internet](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-Up/Languages.htm)). This has not always been the case; there was a time when automatic language switching only worked between speech synthesis engines from the same brand (and not every brand).
- In NVDA, automatic language switching should work with [Vocalizer for NVDA](https://vocalizer-nvda.com/docs/en/userguide.html#automatic-language-switching-settings) and with a [version of Eloquence that supports language switching](https://jeff.tdrealms.com/NVDA.md).
- Many screen reader users are used to listening to foreign language texts spoken by a speech synthesizer for their native language.
- Language switching does not only affect speech synthesis but also the Braille table that is loaded for the Braille display. Since Braille codes for punctuation vary between languages, automatic language switching is not necessarily an advantage for Braille display users.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `lang` attribute (and `xml:lang` in XHTML) is the right way.

Not all screen readers support `lang`, though, and for those that do support it, not necessarily all languages are supported.

If the screen reader claims to support it, but it still doesn’t work, you could try to add a `div` container with the `lang` attribute (just taking a wild guess here, maybe the screen reader has issues when it’s only specified on the `textarea` element).

(Note that the `placeholder` of the German `textarea` should also be in German.)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it the correct way but unless you have different languages installed with your screen reader, you may not hear a difference.  You didn't mention which screen reader you're using.

With VoiceOver, at least on iOS, I think you get most languages by default.  I'm not sure about VoiceOver on the Mac.  With [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SupportedSpeechSynths) and [JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/Synthesizers), I'm pretty sure you have to install language packs.

The following all automatically switch languages.  It worked with VoiceOver on iOS.

```
<label for="eninput">this is in english</label>
<textarea id="eninput"></textarea><br>

<label for="deinput">das ist in deutsch</label>
<textarea id="deinput" lang="de"></textarea><br>

<label for="frinput">c'est en français</label>
<textarea id="frinput" lang="fr"></textarea><br>

<label for="ruinput">это по-французски</label>
<textarea id="ruinput" lang="ru"></textarea><br>
```

Note that the `lang` attribute is on the `<textarea>` and not the `<label>` because it's the textarea that receives focus.  There are some nuances with VoiceOver, however.  If I use the normal swipe right gesture to navigate through the fields, the focus moves from field to field and I hear the language switch.  But if I tap the label directly and put focus on it, then the label itself is read in English, because the `<label>` does not have a `lang` attribute.

In your case, you have the `<label>` as the container so if the language is on the container, then everything inside will have the language too.  So the following also works:

```
<label for="frinput" lang="fr">c'est en français
  <textarea id="frinput"></textarea><br>
</label>
```

When focus moves to the field, it's read in French.  If I intentionally tap on the label itself, it's also read in French.

If I wanted my first code sample to work, having the `<label>` and the `<textarea>` as siblings, then I could have a `<div>` container with the language set.

```
<div lang="fr">
  <label for="frinput">c'est en français</label>
  <textarea id="frinput"></textarea><br>
</div>
```

(Note that in all my examples, I always specify the `for` attribute on the `<label>` to **explicitly** associate the label with its respective `<textarea>`, even if the textarea is nested inside the label.  There are some combinations of screen reader and browser where even if the textarea is nested in the label (an **implicit** label), the label is not properly associated with the textarea.  I always play it safe and specify `for`.)